# IEEE 754 Why can't we exactly represent the number n=1+2^30?

Tags: precision, numeric, ieee-754

I've read that if we try to represent this number according to the Standard I will obtain the just the number **1**. Then the absolute error would be **2^30**. I know how to represent a number in IEEE 754 but in this case is a **"sum"** and I don't know how to proceed. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: In what context was the claim made? Typically the result ought to be roughly 2^30, either the exact sum or rounded depending on the IEEE-754 resolution/type.

Comment: @doynax Thanks for answering. The number is an example of a number between 1 and 2 which according to the IEEE-754 can't be represented.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `1+2^-30` then (1.000000000931322574615478515625 as opposed to 1073741825)? Even so it would only need to be truncated in 32-bit single precision and not in double/quad precision formats.